# Xamarin Forms MessagingCenter not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, messagingcenter

In short, it's probably something silly because I have other Messaging Centres throughout my code and I'm struggling to get this one to work for some reason. Here is the Subscribe.

```cs
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NewChatModel>(this, "UpdateList", (message) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello There");
});
```

And here is the send

```cs
MessagingCenter.Send(this, "UpdateList");
```

The class the send is in is NewChatModel, however, for some reason I cannot get the MessagingCenter to trigger to the subscription, any ideas?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center you need to send the message, add to collection is not enough

Comment: @JanKosmala Sorry, that was my fault, I had pasted in the wrong piece of code, I've edited my original post to include the send element now

Comment: MessagingCenter.Send<NewChatModel>(this, "UpdateList");

Comment: could you give more code? it's hard to say  what's wrong without the context. I just build a "clean" app when it works (on M$ sample)

code: https://github.com/accent/test_messaging

Comment: Whether the subscribed class is instantiated and subscribed before sending the message